# Comparing NSDate

Tags: swift, compare, nsdate

I would like to compare two NSDates however every date shows as being "Earlier" than *todaysDate*. Any ideas?

```
let compareResult = self.todaysDate.compare(self.date)

if compareResult == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending {
println("Today is later than date2")
} else {
println("Future")
}
```

To get *"todaysDate"*

```
let todaysDate = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: todaysDate)
let hour = components.hour
let minutes = components.minute
let month = components.month
let year = components.year
let day = components.day
println(todaysDate)
```

This print is:

```
2014-11-12 14:48:48 +0000
```

and the print for *"date"* is:

```
2014-10-24 07:24:41 +0000
```

This is on a Parse.com server.

Thanks

Comment: Will you please show the lines that set `self.todaysDate` and `self.date`?

Comment: `let todaysDate = NSDate()` `let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()` 
        `let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: todaysDate)`
        `let hour = components.hour`
        `let minutes = components.minute`
        `let month = components.month`
        `let year = components.year`
        `let day = components.day` and the other date is retrieved from Parse.com

Comment: The output of `println(self.date)` and `println(self.todaysDate)` would be helpful.

Comment: Did you check to see if every date is actually earlier than today's date?  The example you provided doesn't show an issue.

Answer (score 10):

I think perhaps you're interpreting the results of `compare` backwards. Check this out. Each of the `asserts` passes:

```
let today = NSDate()
let tomorrow = today.dateByAddingTimeInterval(24 * 60 * 60)
let yesterday = today.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-24 * 60 * 60)

assert(today.compare(tomorrow)  == .OrderedAscending)     // today < tomorrow
assert(today.compare(yesterday) == .OrderedDescending)    // today > yesterday
assert(today.compare(today)     == .OrderedSame)          // today == today
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to support `==`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, or `>=` for `NSDate`s, you just have to declare this somewhere:

```
public func ==(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs === rhs || lhs.compare(rhs) == .OrderedSame
}

public func <(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == .OrderedAscending
}

extension NSDate: Comparable { }
```

Implementing `==` and `<` lets `Comparable` infer the other comparison operators.

Usage:

```
let date1 = NSDate()
let date2 = NSDate()

println(date2 > date1) // true
println(date2 < date1) // false
println(date2 == date2) // true
```

Answer (score 1):

try this! you can check for different date by assigning it to strdate

```
    todaysDate = NSDate()
    println(todaysDate)

    var dateformmatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateformmatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    let strdate:NSString = "2014-12-12 07:24:41";
    date = dateformmatter.dateFromString(strdate)!;
    println(date)

    let compareResult = todaysDate.compare(date)

    if compareResult == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending {
        println("Today is later than date2")
    } else {
        println("Future")
    }
```

Comment: Every result is returning future. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: no! you have to change strdate value to different date! ex take strdate = "2014-10-10 07:24:41"